# Starting macbook air automatically

Tags: macbook-pro

How could I possibly eliminate the user accounts at login to start my mac automatically?

Actually I have a couple of user accounts both admin / guest however I do not want to login by entering passwords..

How could I set it up such that it starts automatically without requiring any verification?

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can. On `System Preferences → Users & Groups` under `Login Options` you have `Automatic login` where you can chose an user.

When you select an user there, It will automatically login when you switch your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable `FileVault` and then it would allow automatic login.
But be aware thats not good for your information protection.. your mac would be vulnerable..